# Haman's sons in three p'sukim

Tags: megillat-esther, parashas-shemos

Me (quoting *Ester* 9:7–10):

> <sup>7</sup> And *Parshandasa* and *Dalfon* and *Aspasa*
>   <sup>8</sup> and *Porasa* and *Adalya* and *Aridasa*
>   <sup>9</sup> and *Parmashta* and *Arisay* and *Ariday* and *Vayzasa*,
>   <sup>10</sup> the tensome of the sons of *Haman ben Ham'dasa*, terrorizer of the Jews, they killed....

My kid: Why are the ten names split up over three *p'sukim*?

Me: I don't know. Maybe it was too long for one?

My kid: I've seen *p'sukim* longer than all three put together!

Me: Good point.

---

The truth is that, as noted in a comment, this question may be a little weak — perhaps that's just how the authors of *Ester* liked to write — but the same question applies to [*Sh'mos* 1:2–4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0201), where I expect a stronger answer than "the author just liked to write that way". So consider my question to be about those (and similar) *p'sukim* in *Chumash* instead, if you prefer, although I ideally would still like an  answer about the specific *p'sukim* in *Ester* quoted above.

Comment: I don't think you have such a strong question. It just is that way. See for example Chronicles I 1:1-4 and many many other places in Chronicles and around Tanach.

Comment: @DoubleAA, like _Sh'mos_ 1:2–4. I agree it's not the strongest question (and it's not mine), but I couldn't, and can't, answer it, so am asking it here. I find it hard to believe, especially in _Chumash_, that it "just is that way" with no reason. (In _Nach_, fine, maybe it's for poetic reasons or that's just how the author liked to write, but in _Chumash_ I'm not as happy with that answer.) I'll edit my question to be about _Sh'mos_ rather than _Ester_.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68720

Comment: somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88343/is-there-a-list-of-three-word-pesukim-in-tanakh.  Looking through the list (as well as searching tanach for 4 word pesukim) should help you prove that in general, long lists of names are broken up into multiple Pesukim, sometimes even into three and four word pesukim.

Answer (score -4):

It seems to me that in general, pasukim are broken up so that there are no more than 3-4 names in a verse, especially a list.

Why this is done I imagine is up to speculation.  Does it have mystical numerical meanings? (i.e. stability), does it have to do with human memory and good oration? (Saying things in threes makes it a stronger point, and more likely to be remembered), or is it just the style that the people who decided to break verses up into verses chose to use?  ([Normally christian monks btw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible))

I imagine all the possible answers are correct on some level.

Comment: "[T]he people who decided to break verses up into verses" are "[n]ormally [C]hristian monks"?? The _g'mara_ refer to _p'sukim_ as that which "_paskeh Moshe_", "Moshe demarcated it".

Comment: @msh210 could be, but we have no idea if they are the same as not. Infact we know that the Torah described in the Talmud is marked differently than our own, regarding the middle word/letter.

Comment: @msh210 The gemara in Nedarim 38a "Amar Rav Acha bar Ahava" says that there was a dispute between the Babylonians and the Israelis how to break up the pasuk that we call Shemot 19:9 It seems we can't be too sure that all of our pasuk breaks are LeMoshe MiSinai.

Comment: @DoubleAA, then we see that we do have a tradition (in that case, two traditions) about how to split up _p'sukim_. Perhaps, avi, the Babylonians and Israelis in question got their traditions from monks? Benedict, who (it seems) started the tradition of monkhood, lived before the _chasimas haTalmud_, so I suppose you could argue that. I, for one, highly doubt it.

Comment: @msh210 No, the breaking up of chapter and verse is from the 1300s way after the Rambam and the mesorites made their tekunim.  It seems that in later years the monks corrected their verses to match up with the trope.

Comment: avi, I'm not sure what you're saying in your last comment. I am not trying to argue that the division into chapters (and therefore numbering of verses) was late. I'm only saying the division into *verses* was early. Did your last comment address that at all?

Comment: @msh210 I agree that much of our text is based on mesorah. All I'm saying is that we know some of the psukim stops have changed, and it's not unreasonable to assume that some monks had the final word in which opinions ended up being printed around the world.

Comment: @avi, the *numeration* of chapters and verses is from the 1300s. The *division* into verses goes back long before that, as msh210 said. (And most of ours do match up with the ones from the time of the Gemara, as evidenced by the fact that Kiddushin 30a says that the Torah contains 5888 verses, where we have 5846 - an agreement of over 99%.)

Comment: @Alex (Those numbers are insufficient to prove our divisions match the _G'mara_'s: perhaps they're ~equal in number but not in actual dividing points.)

Comment: Only that the trope and therefore verse endings, we have today come from Rambam's time, or Allepo, I'm a bit foggy on exactly who won that debate.

Comment: Let's settle this SE style http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13524/759