# List of Sha’ar page pesukim to years

Tags: jewish-books, tanach

As is known, many sefarim use a pasuk to correspond to the current year. Is there a list or program that makes a list?

I am referring to when a part (or whole) of a pasuk is equal in gematria to the current year.

Comment: I think that many Gematriya calculators (I think Toras Emes and Bar Ilan's calculators, as well as a couple of them online) will provide phrases that are parts of Pesukim, so just type in the year as the word you want to find a Gematriya of, and it should match you up to Pesukim.  That would give a list of appropriate matches for whatever year you would input.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Sure! Go online and search for a gematria program/search engine. In that program, simply input the year's Hebrew date, and you will get a listing of phrases from tanach that match that gematria. Also, if you want, just post a Hebrew year that you are looking for, and I'll give you the list in an answer.

Comment: I’m really just looking for a pasuk corresponding in gematria to 5788 (788)

Comment: would you like me to post Pesukim with that Gematria as an answer?

Comment: Yes that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Shmuel's comments above:

Full Pesukim of Gematria 5788 are Yehoshua 22:14 and Yirmiyahu 13:27.

Full Pesukim of Gematria 788 are Ezra 10:42 and Nechemia 12:20.

There are way too many partial Pesukim to list that have a Gematria of 5788 and 788 to post here, but here are some examples that I liked:

788 - משתה גדול (Bereishis 21:8), בכסף מלא יתננה לי (Bereishis 23:9), ישראל בקהל עם (Shoftim 20:2), ויספרו מעשיו (Tehillim 107:22).

5788 - אשר ישבתם בה לא תעשו וכמעשה ארץ כנען אשר אני מביא אתכם שמה לא תעשו ובחקתיהם (Vayikra 18:3), ויאמר למה זה ירדת ועל מי נטשת מעט הצאן ההנה במדבר אני ידעתי את זדנך ואת רע לבבך כי למען ראות המלחמה ירדת (Shmuel A, 17:28).

I used the Bar Ilan Responsa Project 21+ to find these.  If you would like me to look for anything more specific, let me know.

Comment: We are in the year 5778, not 5788. Is this just a typo in your answer, or is the entire answer based on an inaccurate number?

Comment: @chaim the op asked for 5788, for whatever reason.

Comment: See comments to the question

Answer (score 2):

Shalom, I  suggest Razei DeRazim, an awesome software, free for Windows.
It is a Tanakh searching tool, Gematria search, on full pasuk or part, rashei teivot abd sofei teivot, Atbash and other search tricks, ... 
It's useful to the Year Gematria, and more.

https://sites.google.com/site/rderazim/home

Comment: Does this give phrases as well as full pesukim? Many Sefarim that I’ve seen will give a phrase that corresponds to the year, even if it’s not a full passuk.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**

The OP has asked me to leave this answer and the pointers available even though it does not answer the question as clarified (referring to gematria). I will therefore leave it accessible to those who cannot see deleted posts

---

One of the ways of doing this is to use the pasuk whose number corresponds to the year which is dated. Thus the first pasuk in Bereishis is the first year, pasuk 1948 corresponds to the year Avraham was born, pasuk 5708 matches the year of the founding of the state of Israel (as examples). I ask the question where this comes from at [Where is the source for assigning a pasuk to each year since creation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67516/where-is-the-source-for-assigning-a-pasuk-to-each-year-since-creation) and go over the actual counts at [Count of Pesukim in each Parsha](https://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2016/01/count-of-pesukim-in-each-parsha.html)

In order to determine which pasuk refers to the current year, take the count at that I show for the sefer and add the number of pesukim in each parsha of sefer devarim and then determine which pasuk is meant. For example, I show that the last pasuk of vayeilech is equivalent to the secular year 1986 and the last pasuk of Ha'azinu is equivalent to secular year 2038. The current year (5778 - 2018) is 20 pesukim from the end of Ha'azinu [53:2] so the current year would be  [Ha'azinu 32:34](http://torahweek.blogspot.com/2012/12/missing-pesukim.html)

> הֲלֹא־ה֖וּא כָּמֻ֣ס עִמָּדִ֑י חָת֖וּם בְּאֽוֹצְרֹתָֽי:
>
> 34 Is it not stored up with Me, sealed up in My treasuries?

Also [Ha'azinu 32:34](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Devarim/32.34#e0n6)

Comment: The OP was looking for a program. This is more of a comment.

Comment: I may have been a little unclear @sabahillel, I was referring to when a part (or whole) of a pasuk is equal in gematria to the current year.

Comment: @ezra The OP asked for a program or a list. I pointed him to the list of years for each parsha. I give the year and equivalent secular year for the end of each parsha and explain how to find the specific year within that parsha.

Comment: @Shmuel. OK That is different from what I answered. I will delete this answer and put your clarification in the question.

Comment: It’s still good info, leave it.