# What are pesukim or phrases from pesukim with the gematria of either 5781 or 781

Tags: gematria-numerology

> I'm publishing a sefer and in place of the date i want to write a pasuk or phrase that represents this year 5781.

Comment: https://thetrugmans.com/word-and-gematria-search/#

Comment: Shut up שת אפ .

Comment: You might struggle to get only part of a pasuk which stops midway through what is being said...

Comment: @Dov 5781 - not 5771.....

Comment: Hi Aron, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Check out this other question, which might help you find an answer:
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89514/16354

Comment: Seemingly this is Primarily Opinion Based as is. There's no specified way to evaluate the quality of a given answer

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11139/759

Comment: I'm currently developing an app that finds Gematrias of Pesukim, and I found the following 2 Pesukim (ויקרא ג׳:ב and דברים כ׳:ח) which each equal 5781 (couldn't find any for 781):
וסמך ידו על־ראש קרבנו ושחטו פתח אהל מועד וזרקו בני אהרן הכהנים את־הדם על־המזבח סביב
And also
ויספו השטרים לדבר אל־העם ואמרו מי־האיש הירא ורך הלבב ילך וישב לביתו ולא ימס את־לבב 
אחיו כלבבו

Answer (score 0):

Try Tehillim 20:7.

The phrase, “הושיע יהוה משיחו” is gematria 781. In that context see the comments of Malbim and Radak for understanding.