# Psikim in the sons of Haman

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, trop-cantillation

In the listing of the sons of Haman, there's a psik after each ואת.  Normally when there's a psik, we pause a little bit.

However, in this case we read the entire list in one breath.  With practice, I've found that I can pause for the psikim and still manage that, but pausing seems to be a conceptual contradiction to reading the names fast, and I've never heard anyone else actually do it.

Are these psikim supposed to be treated normally?  Or are they some kind of quasi-taam tachton, and we should pause for them when learning but not when reading the Megilla to be yotzei on Purim?

Comment: Who said anything about reading them fast?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's kind of forced if you're going to read them in one breath.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13502

Comment: This is a very difficult post to answer, as most sources don't state that the notes are standard, in all likelihood because they thought that was obvious.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm satisfied with that as an answer, if nobody says otherwise then we should treat them normally.  I was just hoping someone would discuss the tension between stressing that they all died at the same time (hence reading them in one breath) and pausing in between their names (probably the highest density of psikim in Tanach, as far as I remember, even higher than Bereishit 18:15)

Comment: In Torah Shelema there in the footnote it quotes (maybe from the Rokeach?) that the Psiks between each name indicate other people who were killed too.