# Is there a list of three-word pesukim in tanakh?

Tags: tanach

In [Ma'amodos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807&st=&pgnum=525&hilite=), there is a list of the 14 pesukim that have three words each that are found in the 5 books of Torah. Is there a list of three-word pesukim in Tanakh? The reason I have asked this question is because of curiosity.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Try here http://tora.us.fm/tnk1/klli/limud/xipus.html I think there is some way to do it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why do you want to know why he wants to know?

Comment: @Loewian It's a very bizarre request which seems completely pointless. I certainly have no interest in wasting my time on it. Some motivation would likely make others more interested in donating their valuable time to the OP. Plus perhaps some background would help someone better able to address his underlying issue whatever that might be.

Comment: I think that if you put in some background as to why Ma'modos (I don't know what that is, actually. Maybe, include a link to that source?) thinks this is important, you would enhance the question and the motivation for asking this. Offhand, outside of Divrei Hayamim, I don't think Tanac"h has any 3 word pesukim. FYI, you do know that the shortest pasuk in the Torah is 2 words? You should know where those are.

Comment: @DanF What two-word pesukim?

Comment: @joshua לא תרצח is the first that comes to mind

Comment: @DoubleAA is exactly right. And, of course, the few verses after that one. And, incidentally, they are all in their own parsha making them the shortest parshiot in the Torah.

Comment: Duh! Go figure that most of them come from Tehillim and they are the same words but in different places. I should have known that. Reminder - See my first comment. The way this question looks, now, it's close to being a riddle. What's so important about 3 word psukim?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you are right then why is the טעם התחתון of aforementioned posuk (or pesukim) as if it is indeed one posuk?

Comment: @JoshuaPearl If you are right then why is the טעם העליון of the aforementioned posuk (or pesukim) as if it is indeed four pesukim?

Comment: The Gemara (Kidushin 30a) already mentions that Israel and Bavel had variant verse divisions. So in Israel they split these verses like what we call Taam Tachton and in Bavel they split it like what we call Taam Elyon. Yemenites who were very close with Bavel (and kept things like Bavli Nikud) only have a tradition of Elyon. Ashkenazim who had a closer connection with Israeli traditions maintained Tachton for most readings. The masoretic notes to the Parsha are obviously Bavli (since in Israel they used triennial breaks) while the notes to the book are Israeli as is most of our Tanakh material

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you - I did not know of this variation between Bovel and Yisroel

Comment: Truth be told, while that is the "standard" explanation of the history, it doesn't quite explain why even the great Tiberian manuscripts mentioned only this allegedly Babylonian tradition or why the Gemara doesn't use it as an example of where Maarava differs. Some things we may just never know... But in any event it's clear that there's little reason to suspect the Tachton division is any more authoritative than the Elyon division.

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume the "# mi yodeya?" series make you gnash your teeth every time you come across them.

Comment: @Loewian As far as site policy goes, those questions are grandfathered in and should not be used as examples of good questions for Mi Yodeya. I assume you wouldn't upvote a question I could pose asking for all 6 word verses that are followed by 7 word verses and preceded by verses containing a Tzadi-Sofit? I assume you would think it reasonable to ask why I'd want to know that?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm pretty sure I've seen such questions allowed even after any such rule change. Unless you mean that even follow-up questions are also grandfathered in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to רבות מחשבות, I have found an answer. [Here](http://tora.us.fm/tnk/find.php?q=%5E%5B%D7%90-%D7%AA%27%5D%2B%20%5B%D7%90-%D7%AA%27%5D%2B%20%5B%D7%90-%D7%AA%27%5D%2B%24) is the list of all 142 three-word pesukim in Tanakh.