# What is the shortest pasuk

Tags: tanach

What is the shortest verse?
Someone asked me and i did not have an answer

In the tenach?
In the chumash?

How about second to shortest.

How did you find it?

Comment: It's at least a 4 way tie: לא תרצח. לא תנאף. לא תגנב. לא תרצח. How are you measuring length by the way? Letters? Words? Trop clauses? Syllables?

Comment: @DoubleAA all ways

Comment: This is not according to all versions. There is the *Taam Tachton* in  which all 4 are 1 passuk.

Answer (score 2):

I googled “הפסוק הקצר ביותר" and followed the first two hits.

[1 Divrei Hayomim 1 (1)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16521)

אָדָ֥ם שֵׁ֖ת אֱנֽוֹשׁ:

[Beraishis 26 (6)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8221)

וַיֵּ֥שֶׁב יִצְחָ֖ק בִּגְרָֽר:

[Beraishis 49 (18)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8244)

לִֽישׁוּעָֽתְךָ֖ קִוִּ֥יתִי ה':

Interestingly, the two-word pesukim mentioned by DoubleAA were not listed. See [Shemos 20 (13)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9881)  where they are listed as one possuk.

Comment: In what way are the latter two shorter than ובני דן חשים?

Comment: Not all the verse I cited are in Shemot 20 (not that the modern invention of chapter or verse numbers is Halakhically relevant at all)

Comment: @DoubleAA Verse “numbers” may be a relatively modern invention but the division of verses -where they begin and end- is a dispute in Nedarim 37a-b whether or not they are *Halachah LeMoshe MiSinai*. (Ra”n ibid. interprets *ha’pessukim* as the ‘periods’. On the topic, I’d be grateful if you can explain how/if Ra”n differentiates bet. *pessukim* and *pissuk ta’amim*.)

Comment: The two-word pesukim are only counted separately in Ta’am Elyon; in Ta’am Tachton, which the traditional numbering follows, they are indeed counted together.

Comment: @JoelK You are right. Surprising chushim isn't mentioned. Maybe he didn't hear the question?

Comment: @Doniel "traditional numbering" ???? What nonsense is this? They are both traditional ways of splitting up the verses. If anything Taam Elyon is more traditional since not all Jews even have a tradition of Taam Tachton at all. It's just a thing some Jews have extra.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Also all of [these](http://tora.us.fm/tnk/find.php?q=%5E%5B%D7%90-%D7%AA%27%5D%2B%20%5B%D7%90-%D7%AA%27%5D%2B%20%5B%D7%90-%D7%AA%27%5D%2B%24) ([source](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88361/1569))

Comment: @ba in particular עבר פלג רעו only 9 letters

Comment: @DoubleAA What I mean is the numbering which most modern Chumashim use. Whatever semantics you want to use to describe it.

Comment: @Doniel I want to use semantics which aren't false given their common meaning. Your comment implies some Judaism basis for preferring not counting them as verses.

Comment: @ba Winning source. I can edit your comment into my answer if you like - but better still why not post it as an answer yourself?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok You can edit it in if you want. I am more persuaded by Double AA's two-word verses, though